# How to connect XML to resource folders

Tags: java, android

Alright so I have been reading Android's tutorial on how to support multiple screen sizes (https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali) and I do not know what they are doing, I have gotten as far as to make multiple folders like "sw600dp" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4ihy.jpg), but I do not know how to connect the XMLs to the right folder does anyone know how?! Thanks

Comment: not sure what you're talking about. The folders you create which target specific Android versions or screen sizes will hold resources which also target those versions/sizes. Android will automatically handle that for you.

Comment: @TylerSebastian What I am saying is when I create a bunch of layouts that are the same, except some images are bigger or smaller due to the screen size how do I make sure Android knows which layout is dedicated to which?

Comment: If I create a folder called `values-w820dp` and I put a bunch of `.xml` files in there (let's say a `dimens.xml`), when the app is run on a device which matches the requirements for the folder (i.e. width of > 820dp), Android will automatically apply the values in the `dimens.xml` over, say, the `dimens.xml` in the `values` folder.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Ohhh okay, so if I wanted to make a button larger if the screen size has a width of 820dp, I would also put that in the dimens.xml rather than creating a bunch of different layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see folder like "values-w820p" and many more in your project's resources folder. These are the folders that are specific to a particular screen resolution.

So for instance you put a image in the folder values-820p, when the use runs your app on such resolution device. This folder of your app will be automatically be accessed.

In short you can create folders for specific resolutions and then put images for that that resolution in these folders.